# Integrating Spring hibernate-spatial and Solr

Tags: hibernate-spatial, solr

For a new project I'm looking for a more "mainstream" like server side web development technology stack. This question could also be asked in Stack Overflow, but as we also use GeoServer and the Java topology suite (JTS) it has a very strong GIS relevance in my opinion.

As I already mentioned we use JTS and GeoServer and therefore want to stay on the Java platform.

We use Hibernate as an O/R Mapping Framework because it also offers robust mapping of spatial data types over Hibernate-Spatial.

As a new feature we want to integrate Solr as search and indexing server. The Integration with the data that is read or written (by Hibernate-Spatial) should be as seamless as possible.

Spring offers the integration we would like to have, so we can trigger indexing after every database action.

Does that all also fit together if we want to use Hibernate-Spatial with Spring?

Are there any version dependencies?

Do you know better alternatives to integrate these technologies?

Do you have experiences and know good tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Gisgraphy](http://www.gisgraphy.com) use both, hibernate spatial and solr, you can have a look at the [source code](http://www.gisgraphy.com/source-repository.html). I have develop a personal db-to-solr synchronizer because some entities were not concerned by synchronisation.

Answer (score 4):

You could look at [Integrating Hibernate and Solr](http://anotherjavaday.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/combining-power-of-hibernate-search-and.html) for a working example of how to connect Hibernate with Solr through Hibernate Search.